# "the deed" "the mortgage" can they convey general meanings?

Tags: definite-articles, general-vs-specific

I reckon there are three types of general meanings in English using the definite article:

(1) The I-phone is a popular gadget nowadays.

(2) The steel industry is the business of producing steel.

(3) The Mediterranean (Sea) is a sea connected to the Atlantic Ocean.

Then, in which category would these examples below fit?

"***The deed*** is the basic document used to transfer an estate or other interest in land during the owner's lifetime."

"***The mortgage*** is viewed as the transfer of an interest in real property."

Both of the words convey general meanings, but how? My guess is that these are similar to (3): there were other words after 'deed' and 'mortgage' but we often omit them.

Comment: Why do you think *deed* and *mortgage* are shortened versions of something else? Why are *the deed*, *the mortgage* not similar to *the I-phone*?

Comment: The reason, from my point of view, was that (1) is limited to such cases as when the noun is a new device or invention: specifically, physical and tangible objects. I assumed (3) because I saw people saying "a mortgage loan" instead of "mortgage," so that is why. But I think you are right: the examples work like (1).

Comment: The combination of definite article and a singular noun is often used to discuss a class of items. You could also say *Deeds are ...* and proceed with the definition. Similarly, *the dog is a descendant of the wolf.* An individual eample is being used to describe the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we are speaking of a noun and have no particular instance of it in mind, we normally use the indefinite "a":

> You get **a** deed when you buy **a** house.

Now, let's say we're in a law school class on real estate, and the professor is introducing various terms and explaining them.

> **The** deed is ...
>
> **The** mortgage is ...

The professor is not referring to a particular deed for a particular house at 123 Main Street, or to a particular 20-year mortgage with a fixed interest rate of 5.4%, so why use the definite article there—why "the"?

The definite article there "culls" the item out of a group of related items, making it the subject of focus. That is the extent of its particularity—it is that thing on which we are focusing our attention at this moment, a thing in a set of other things that belong together for some reason.

> The polar bear has white fur.

We are not talking about a particular polar bear that weighs 500 kilos and stands 357cm tall,  but about the generic polar bear *as distinct from* the brown bear, say, or the black bear, or as distinct from other furred animals, the lynx, the hare, the bobcat, the moose, etc.

> The iPhone is an Apple product.

Same thing there.  The iPhone *as distinct from* the Galaxy or the Blackberry or the ...

Comment: I hear what you say, but I still think it is idiomatic to say *the deed* when you mean deeds in general. *The will is a document whose contents only becomes public knowledge when it is proved*. It is not frequently used in that way but there is no reason why it can't be. At least that is how, in Britain, I would see the position.

Comment: @WS2: Your use of the phrase "a document" is in accord with my item-in-a-set explanation above. We don't really disagree.